# In Kotlin, shouldn't I use "return" when returning a double in a function?

Tags: kotlin

I can build apps but I'm realizing I am lacking some Kotlin knowledge.  I signed up for codewars and the first question is as follows:

Figure out why the code wont work...

```
fun multiply(x: double, y: double) => x * y
```

My answer

```
fun multiply(x: double, y: double) => Double {
return x * y
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no keywork as `double` in Kotlin. Kotlin uses Class type implementation for double type (in JVM it still uses primitive double type)

You can define the function as follows:

`fun multiply(x: Double, y: Double): Double { return x * y }`

or if you wish to have single statement method, then you can define as below

`fun multiply(x: Double, y: Double) = x * y`

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for your help.  I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

you  should use Double in capitalize and change => on :
Your code should seen like this:

```
fun multiply(x:Double, y:Double):Double{
   return x * y
}
```

or

```
fun multiply(x:Double, y:Double):Double = x * y
```